# Report viewer can't access reports in other database server

Tags: c#, asp.net, ssrs-2008

I have a web application in asp.net 3.5 published in apps server.I have few SSRS reports deployed in a database server which needed to be accessed from the web app.Both the server are in same network.I am using a report viewer control to show the reports and i am passing the report path dynamically.I am also sending the login credentials from code behind.

The problem is that the report is identified correctly and the proper report parameter are also shown.But when i click the view report button no data appears.I have Sql server 2008 r2 and report viewer version 9.0

Please help me with this. here is a code snippet...

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!IsPostBack)
    {
        ReportViewer1.ShowCredentialPrompts = false;

        IReportServerCredentials irsc = 
            new CustomReportCredentials("user", "pass", "domain");

        ReportViewer1.ServerReport.ReportServerCredentials = irsc;
        ReportViewer1.ServerReport.ReportServerUrl = 
            new Uri("http://72.0.170.205:80/ReportServer");

        ReportViewer1.ShowParameterPrompts = true;
        ReportViewer1.ShowPrintButton = true;
        ReportViewer1.ProcessingMode = ProcessingMode.Remote;

        ReportViewer1.ServerReport.Refresh();

        ReportViewer1.ServerReport.ReportPath = Request.QueryString["val"];
    }
}
```

Comment: I think there is some compatibility issue here..in my development environment i used ssrs 2008.and in the production env its ssrs 2008 r2.Can any one help me with how to get the latest version of report viewer in asp.net report viewer controle.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you check that the reports run ok with the same credentials on http://72.0.170.205:80/Reports ?

Don't know if this can be of any help but here are the differences I see in my implementation :

- I don't call ReportViewer1.ServerReport.Refresh();
- I call this.RegisterRequiresViewStateEncryption(); ( Had to disable it sometimes )
- my reportDisplay application is not the root app. Because of conflicts, back in SSRS2005 I had to use a different name for its session cookie in the web.config. Kept it since then

  ```
   <sessionState cookieless="UseCookies" cookieName="ASP.NET_SessionId.myCustomName"/>
  ```

Comment: I have checked that the report runs perfect with the same credentials..Can you tell me in some details on where to create this session cookies??What will be the default name of the cookie?

Comment: The cookie name is defined in the sessionState element of your web.config. Default name should be ASP.NET_SessionId .

Comment: Thanks for your post i added the session and also httphandler to the application configuration and it worked....:)

Answer (score 0):

Protected Sub Load_Report()
        Dim Connection As New SqlConnection(Connection_String) *'Server Connection String*

```
    Dim Data_Table As New DataTable("DataTable1") *'Create New Data Table in DataSet having same columns as are there in your Datatable*
    Dim Query As String
    Query = "SELECT Caption,Mobile,Age,City FROM Bond.Book"
    Dim Command As New SqlCommand(Query, Connection)
    Dim Table_Adapter As New SqlDataAdapter(Command)
    Table_Adapter.Fill(Data_Table)
    ReportViewer1.ProcessingMode = ProcessingMode.Local
    ReportViewer1.LocalReport.ReportPath = Server.MapPath("Book.rdlc")
    ReportViewer1.LocalReport.DataSources.Clear()
    ReportViewer1.LocalReport.DataSources.Add(New ReportDataSource("Book_DataSet", Data_Table))
    ReportViewer1.LocalReport.Refresh()
End Sub
```

This worked for me. I am able to load report viewer on server and view server data